# How to prevent my entire table from being deleted

Tags: go, go-gorm

If for whatever readon my someModel is not found in my first query below, **the delete statement then deletes the entire table**.

```
delete from somemodels
```

What is the best way to prevent this?

```
someModel := &SomeModel{}

db.Where("some_id = ? and other_id = ?", someModel.UserId, someModel.Id).First(&someModel)

db.Delete(&someModel)
```

Currently I am not checking if the model actually was found and returned from the database, and I know I should be checking but what is the best way to do this?

Just check if it is not nil?  model.Id > 0 ?

Answer (score 2):

As you have surmised, it deletes the entire table because the record was not found, i.e. there is nothing in the model that it can use as a criteria, and therefore leaves the criteria blank and removes the entire table.

You can check if the record was found, without checking the model itself.

For instance:

```
if !db.Where("some_id = ? and other_id = ?", someModel.UserId, someModel.Id).First(&someModel).RecordNotFound {
    db.Delete(&someModel)
}

if err := db.Where("some_id = ? and other_id = ?", someModel.UserId, someModel.Id).First(&someModel).Error; err != nil {
    if gorm.IsRecordNotFoundError(err) {
        // record not found
    } else {
        // something else went wrong
    }
} else {
    db.Delete(&someModel)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](http://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#Delete-Record), you need to check whether the primary id is blank. I'm not sure what your model looks like but I guess you should check `modle.ID` is not blank.